# systemd & max open files with elasticsearch on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, systemd

I am trying to set the max open files on CentOS 7 for elasticsearch. I've read over and over again how to set this but it doesn't seem to be working. As I understand it:

- limits.conf is irrelevant because elasticsearch user is set to /sbin/nologin and we're starting the daemon with system
- I need to set `LimitNOFILE=65535` in the systemd unit file.

So, I went ahead and did that, here's my unit file, it's provided by the [elasticsearch puppet module](https://github.com/elastic/puppet-elasticsearch):

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts and stops a single elasticsearch instance on this system
Documentation=http://www.elasticsearch.org

[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch-graylog2
User=elasticsearch
Group=elasticsearch
PIDFile=/var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-graylog2.pid
ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -d -p /var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-graylog2.pid -Des.default.path.home=${ES_HOME} -Des.default.path.logs=${LOG_DIR} -Des.default.path.data=${DATA_DIR} -Des.default.path.work=${WORK_DIR} -Des.default.path.conf=${CONF_DIR}
# See MAX_OPEN_FILES in sysconfig
LimitNOFILE=65535
# See MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY in sysconfig, use "infinity" when MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited and using bootstrap.mlockall: true

# Shutdown delay in seconds, before process is tried to be killed with KILL (if configured)
TimeoutStopSec=20

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note how `limitNOFILE` is set here. I have also set MAX_OPEN_FILES in my EnvironmentFile:

```
CONF_DIR=/etc/elasticsearch/graylog2
CONF_FILE=/etc/elasticsearch/graylog2/elasticsearch.yml
ES_GROUP=elasticsearch
ES_HOME=/usr/share/elasticsearch
ES_USER=elasticsearch
LOG_DIR=/var/log/elasticsearch/graylog2
MAX_OPEN_FILES=65535
```

However, elasticsearch still reports that the max open files are 4096, both from within the app itself, and from with `/proc/<pid>/limits`

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? I even tried setting this from within `limits.conf` but as I expected, no luck.

Comment: This smells like the work SELinux to me...

Comment: SELinux is disabled, first thing I checked.
`sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled`

Comment: I have exact the same configs as you and it works fine on mine.. Sorry I can't be much help

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

```
/etc/security/limits.d/elasticuser
# Default limit for number of open files for elastic user
elastic hard nofile 65536
```

And included this in systemd like you did

```
LimitNOFILE=65536
```

seems to work fine

Answer (score -1):

User cannot be set to /sbin/nologin, this is the path to its shell. So you need to tune your limits.conf

Comment: That's what I meant, the elasticsearch user has shell `/sbin/nologin`

Comment: Type of shell doesn't matter. Anyway you can try the following 
1. Find out under which user elasticsearch is running. 
2. In user's .bash_profile add 'ulimit -n unlimited' 
3. If it works reduce 'unlimited' to reasonable value.

Comment: That didn't help, as I expected, because .bash_profile is only executed by a login shell

Comment: try to add in .bashrc as well